# Almost Always Auto and for loops with counter

Tags: c++, c++11

Herb Sutter states [Almost Always Auto](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) and I have the following code:

```
using count_t = int;
count_t get_count() { ... };

const auto count = get_count();
for (decltype(count) i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // Do the stuff
}
```

Essentially, using `decltype()` allows me to write a for loop that may use any integer type (hoping that `get_count()` would never return floating point) without any modifications in a client code of `get_count()` function and avoid compilation warnings like "signed-unsigned" mismatch.

My question is: is this form acceptable at all in an assumption that `count_t` may be redefined in future?

Comment: What do you mean by acceptable ?

Comment: Acceptable to whom?

Comment: Since he also demands to not write raw loops anymore, I would say no. :-) http://www.randomprogramming.com/2014/04/no-raw-loops-2/

Comment: Do you understand `auto` and `decltype`?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Given that he's using them correctly, why would you ask that?

Comment: @Sneftel I'm trying to make sense of the question, because I don't understand it.

Comment: I would use count_t, since it's an alias it will track changes. Almost always auto doesn't mean even if it makes your code more complicated.

Comment: What is your use case and concern? Why do you think this might not be acceptable?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think he's just asking whether it's okay not to use `auto` for the loop variable, since he wants to take the type from `count` rather than from `0`.

Comment: When you read this code - do you find it acceptable with count_t as an int?  If not, then it's probably not going to be acceptable for any other count_t type.

Comment: Related, If `i` isn't actually needed in the loop, you can alternatively apply: `for (auto count = get_count(); count-- > 0;)`. Like most things, striving for universal application of situational ideology usually leads to more trouble than benefit. Just saying.

Comment: I think this is opinion based. You trade some problems for other. Instead of getting types right, you rather promiscuously adjust to them. If count return something funny it'll remain hidden. If I were to write a generic/templated loop and didn't have power over return type of `get_count` i.e. `count_t`. I'd probably restrict allowed types with `static_assert` to accept the ones I know will work.

Comment: This is completely subjective. For example, I and all my colleagues disagree strongly with AAA.

Comment: @Jarod42 Acceptable for production code.

Comment: @Praetorian to other programmers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To still be AAA, you might go to:

```
for (auto i = decltype(count){}; i != count; ++i) { /*..*/ }
```

Answer (score 4):

If using Boost is an option, you can avoid all the noise

```
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>

for(auto i : boost::irange(get_count()))
```

The single argument version of [`boost::irange`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) was introduced in 1.68, so you will need to copy the [implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/boost/range/irange.hpp) for earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T>
struct indexer_t {
  T t;
  T operator*()const{return t;}
  void operator++(){++t;}
  friend bool operator==(indexer_t const& lhs, indexer_t const& rhs) {
    return lhs.t==rhs.t;
  }
  friend bool operator!=(indexer_t const& lhs, indexer_t const& rhs) {
    return lhs.t!=rhs.t;
  }
};
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b,e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
};
template<class T>
range_t<indexer_t<T>> count_over( T const& s, T const& f ) {
  return { {s}, {f} };
}
template<class T>
range_t<indexer_t<T>> count_upto( T const& t ) {
  return count_over<T>( 0, t );
}

for (auto i : count_upto(count))
{
  // Do the stuff
}
```

`indexer_t` and `range_t` can be improved; they are both minimal implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative. I won't declare it to be better or worse than your own suggestion:

```
for (auto i = 0 * count; i < count; i++) {
```

Note that, as mentioned in comments, this behaves differently compared to yours in case type of `count` is smaller than `int` in which cases my `i` is promoted.

That said, index based loops can usually (perhaps always?) be converted to an iterator based loop, where `auto` deduction is more natural.

Comment: Works great except for types like `short`: `int * short == int`.

Comment: This will throw a bunch of warnings on higher warning levels (signed-unsigned conversion/comparison-related).

Comment: @Rakete1111 for cases where it that makes a difference, good point.

Comment: @rubenvb I got no warnings on GCC using `-Wall -Wextra` neither using signed, nor using unsigned `count`.

Comment: I think this comment "*index based loops can usually be converted to an iterator based loop, where auto deduction is more natural.*" contains most of the value of this answer... I like the spirit of dealing with the problem via preventing them by definition rather than working around.

Comment: Would `auto i = count - count` preserve `i`'s type?

Comment: @user2079303 [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71d3addae5aa75e9) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1782dc9085e2e32b).

Comment: There are cases when iterators get invalidated inside the loop (e.g. `std::vectors` is resized with reallocation).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, no: `char c; auto i = c - c; static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(i), int>);`.

Comment: @rubenvb Your loop is different.

Comment: @user2079303 right-o, missed the 0*size bit, which is the core of your answer. Never mind me :).